# Why is ObservableCollection not updating the UI data grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, observablecollection

I am trying to display customers in my app. I have used WPF with MVVM Light.
When I am switching the view to Customers then I have empty datagrid. Why is it not loading?

My ShellViewModel inherits from BaseViewModel.

I am sending User to my ClientsViewModel from MainViewModel.

ClientsViewModel:

```
public class ClientsViewModel : ShellViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    public Customer customer { get; set; }

    public ClientsViewModel()
    {
        SetView("Klienci");
        Messenger.Default.Register<UserMessage>(this, (message) =>
        {
            try { User = message.User;
                GetCustomers();
            }
            catch (System.InvalidOperationException e) { }
        });

    }

    private void GetCustomers()
    {
        Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();

        using (var context = new mainEntities())
        {
            var result = context.customerassigned.Where(c => c.user_id == User.Id).Include(c => c.customer).Where(c=>c.customer.status_id == 1);
            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                Customers.Add(new Customer(item.customer.id, item.customer.name, item.customer.status_id));
            }

        }
    }
}
```

GetCustomers() method is working fine. 
My datagrid in ClientsView:

```
<DataGrid Name="grdCustomers" SelectedItem="{Binding ClientsView.customer}" ItemsSource="{Binding ClientsView.Customers, Mode=OneWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="true" Height="500"></DataGrid>
```

What should I change?

Comment: `AutoGenerateColumns="tue"` is that a type-o perhaps?

Comment: Besides that an ItemsSource Binding doesn't need to be TwoWay, where is the `ClientsView` property declared that is used in `ItemsSource="{Binding ClientsView.Customers}`. How did you set the view's DataContext?

Comment: Don't you need `INotifypropertychanged`and `INotifyCollectionchanged` interfaces working with MVVM light toolkit? Never used it myself...

Comment: you can use spy to to check if your properties are empty or not  .

Comment: Quite likely, your `GetCustomers` method changes the `Customers` property (assigning a new ObservableCollection instance) **after** the binding has been established. Since the `Customers` property setter is not raising a property change notification when the `Customers` property changes (it doesn't do anything, it's just ye olde trivial auto-implemented property), the binding mechanism won't know that the property has changed and thus wouldn't forward the new ObservableCollection instance to the DataGrid. (A similar issue exists with your `customer` property as well)

Comment: @RolandDeschain yes it is

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ typo, it doesnt matter

Comment: @Clemens DataContex is ok, I have check it already .

Comment: @elgonzo please take a look for my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Don't make a new ObservableCollection instance, just create it one time and populate it as required.

```
public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();

...

private void GetCustomers()
{
    Customers.Clear();

    using (var context = new mainEntities())
    {
        var result = context.customerassigned.Where(c => c.user_id == User.Id).Include(c => c.customer).Where(c=>c.customer.status_id == 1);
        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            Customers.Add(new Customer(item.customer.id, item.customer.name, item.customer.status_id));
        }

    }
}
```

Also, take note of Clemens comments above.

You need to

1) Create an instance of ClientsViewModel and assign that to the DataContext of your View.

2) Bind only to public properties of the ClientsViewModel class - ItemsSouce ==> Customers in this case, not ClientsView.Customers whatever that is.